# DataExporter doesn't export DataTable column headerText

Tags: primefaces

I try to export datatable datas to excel file by dataexporter. DataExporter export datatable column headerTexts when i use primefaces 6.1. But I upgraded to version 12.0.0, dataexporter doesn't export datatable column headerTexts. I use all export header types. But both of them doens'nt work. I checked [primefaces showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml?jfwid=4b29a). It doesn't work at primefaces showcase page. I see "null" when i call getRow(0). Rows start at index 1. But I see first row is empty when i check exported excel file. How can i export headerTexts?

```
<p:column headerText="test" style="width:170px;"
        filterBy="#{variable}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <h:outputText value="test" />
</p:column>


<p:column style="width:170px;"
        filterBy="#{variable}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="test" />
        </f:facet>
        
        <h:outputText value="test" />
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9290

PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/9291

Fixed in PF Elite 12.0.1 and Community 13.0.0

Comment: how can i use 13.0.0?. there is no 13.0.0 in maven

Comment: It doesn't exist yet its the next community release probably in 2023.  Elite 12.0.1+ is the current way to get the version or to build the 13.0 sources yourself.