How to show header name of column in exported xlsx file in Primefaces
I try to export my table to xlxs file with DataTable from Primefaces, the code like this :
The Button :
<p:commandButton styleClass="ui-button-outlined" ajax="false" value="Export" style="margin-right: 10px">
                                    <p:dataExporter target="aktiva passiva" exportHeader="true" type="xls" fileName="neraca(#{libsDateTime.timeNowStr()})" />
                                </p:commandButton>

The Table :
<p:dataTable rendered="false" id="passiva" value="#{tabunganTransaksiBean.getNeracaPassiva(tabunganTransaksiBean.tampilan, UserObj.id_kantor)}" var="ledger">
                            <p:column exportHeaderValue="true" headerText="coa">
                                <h:outputText value="#{ledger.coa}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column exportHeaderValue="true" headerText="nama">
                                <h:outputText value="#{ledger.nama_coa}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column exportHeaderValue="true" headerText="nominal">
                                <h:outputText value="#{libsRendering.minusSign(ledger.balance)}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,###,##0.00"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column exportHeaderValue="true"  headerText="jenis">
                                <h:outputText value="#{ledger.jenis}"/>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>

i have add exportHeader on export button, and exportHeaderValue on table, but the result is header name not show
i want to add header name on exported file xlxs.

Please provide a [mcve] and see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74481269/dataexporter-doesnt-export-datatable-column-headertext
